# Symfony - FOSUserBundle - write into file after login

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

How can I write log into file after user's login?

I have this:

```
<?php
namespace Web\AdminBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;

class LoginListener {

    protected $userManager;

    public function __construct(UserManagerInterface $userManager){
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
    }

    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        $myfile = fopen("login.txt", "w");
        fwrite($myfile, 'some-text');
        fclose($myfile);
    }
}
```

then:

```
login_listener:
    class:  Web\AdminBundle\EventListener\LoginListener
    arguments:
        userManager: "@fos_user.user_manager"
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: onSecurityInteractiveLogin }
```

But this doesn't work, there is no error. I tried just call die('some-text') to make sure it's working, bot it did nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Symfony 3.2 You need to do this in another way.

```
//..src/YourBundle/EventListener/LoginListener.php

namespace YourBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;

class LoginListener
{
/** @var Router */
protected $router;

/** @var TokenStorage */
protected $token;

/** @var EventDispatcherInterface */
protected $dispatcher;

/**
 * @param Router $router
 * @param TokenStorage $token
 * @param EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher
 */
public function __construct(Router $router, TokenStorage $token, EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher)
{
    $this->router       = $router;
    $this->token        = $token;
    $this->dispatcher   = $dispatcher;
}

/**
 * @param InteractiveLoginEvent $event
 */
public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
{
    $this->dispatcher->addListener(KernelEvents::RESPONSE, [$this, 'onKernelResponse']);
}

/**
 * @param FilterResponseEvent $event
 */
public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
{
    $user = $this->token->getToken()->getUser(); // here you have your user


    //Let's write some thing to the file
    $myfile = fopen("login.txt", "w");
    fwrite($myfile, 'some-text');
    fclose($myfile);

    $event->getResponse()->headers->set('Location', $route);
}
```

`

And you need to register this eventListener in services.yml

```
    app.login.listener:
    class: YourBundle\EventListener\LoginListener
    arguments:
        - "@router"
        - "@security.token_storage"
        - "@event_dispatcher"
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, method: onSecurityInteractiveLogin, event: security.interactive_login}
```

Now You can add another logic to the `onKernelResponse()` method

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced a similar problem. I had to increment a database count on every Login. The route I chose was to register a subscriber like this:

```
class LoginSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function handleLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
         // Inser logic here
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => 'handleLogin'
        ];
    }

}
```

And then registering the subscriber as a service that listens to kernel events in your services.yml (or xml if that's the way you roll...):

```
login.subscriber:
    class: Your\Namespace\LoginSubscriber
    tags:
      - {name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

That should do the trick.

Happy Coding !

PS:

Although this approach should work fine across recent version, let me just point out the specific version I used:

- friendsofsymfony/user-bundle         v1.3.6
- symfony/symfony                      v2.8.7

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Symfony 3.2. I think it's different now...  But I'll try.
And fos 2.0

Comment: It should not be. The only mayor difference in our two approaches is using a listener vs. using a subscriber.